# Get YEAR() and MONTH() from a string like "September 2013" in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with column A listing the month of the year in human readable format e.g. "December 2013", and column B listing a calculated value of bills issued in that month (from another sheet).
I would like to make the B value use the A value for the date comparisons in a formula by extracting the month and year. But "December 2013" isn't a date... so how can I get a date/year value from this cell to compare against a proper date listed in another cell?

e.g I currently have a formula like:

`=sum( filter('Invoices Issued'!J:J ;  YEAR('Invoices Issued'!K:K) = 2013 ))`

And I would like to replace "2013" with something like `YEAR(A4)`.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula will help you filter the dates.

### Formula

```
=FILTER(sourceArray, arrayCondition_1,..., arrayCondition_30)
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B, RIGHT(A2:A, 4)="2012", LEFT(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-5)="february"))
```

### Explained

The first  `arrayCondition_1` retrieves the year, having 4 digits, taken from the `RIGHT`. The second `arrayCondition_2` retrieves the month (text), based on the total length of the string minus 5 (digits year plus white space). The `sourceArray` in filtered accordingly and the result is summed up.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[FILTER DATE AS TEXT](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdGZfNlJJWERhTEdob0xGYmtJZGZhX1E&usp=sharing)**